# Nuxt.js import lodash

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, lodash

Just started using Nuxt.js a week ago and I'm not getting the hang of the plugins system.

The relevant part of my `nuxt.config.js` looks like this:

```
// Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/lodash',
],
```

And I created a file named `lodash.js` in the plugins directory that looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import lodash from 'lodash';

Vue.use(lodash);
```

But then in my `.vue` component, when I `console.log('lodash:', this.lodash)`, it prints out `lodash: undefined`, and when I try to use `this.lodash.pick(['a'], { a: 'a', b: 'b' })`, for instance, it throws the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pick' of undefined`.

So then I tried using `this.$lodash` (added an **$**), and when I then `console.log('lodash:', this.$lodash)`, it logs `lodash: ƒ`, and using `console.log('lodash:', this.$lodash())` (calling it like a function) logs `lodash: LodashWrapper {__wrapped__: undefined, __actions__: Array(0), __chain__: false, __index__: 0, __values__: undefined}` (i.e. an object with a bunch of worthless properties).

So then I thought maybe `Vue.use()` isn't the way to go and maybe I should instead inject lodash, so I changed up my lodash.js plugin file to look like this:

```
import lodash from 'lodash';

export default({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('lodash', lodash);
}
```

But that led to *exactly* the same results. And now I don't know what else to try. So my question is how do you install and use lodash (and I suppose any other random npm module) in a nuxt.js project?

FWIW my project's running nuxt version 2.14.12

Answer (score 4):

I've achieved adding lodash into `this.$_` using [Atif Zia's reccomendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66103000/705296) of [vue-lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-lodash).

`plugins/lodash.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueLodash from 'vue-lodash'
import lodash from 'lodash'

Vue.use(VueLodash, { name: '$_', lodash })
```

`nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
...
plugins: ['~/plugins/lodash.js'],
...
}
```

Usage in script:

```js
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };
 
this._.pick(object, ['a', 'c']);
// => { 'a': 1, 'c': 3 }
```

Looking at their GitHub, it looks like this package allows lodash to be webpacked properly.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @PrintlnParams you can eigther use [vue-lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-lodash) package to achieve

`this.$_.sumBy()`.

or you can import lodash as

`import _ from "lodash"`

or individual components as

`import { sumBy } from "lodash"`

to use with Nuxt.Js

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd prefer not to locally import it because I'd like it available on the root object, and I'm trying to get the hang of the plugin system. I briefly tried vue-lodash too, but couldn't get that working either, but if you're willing to show me, I'm willing to try it again.

Comment: Be warned, I have had extensive issues with lodash and SSR when imported on the page in the past..  They may have sorted this now, but generally I would advise native over lodash in middleware/fetch/etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to import Lodash into your Nuxt project locally.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import _ from 'lodash'

const data = [{ name: 'B' }, { name: 'A' }, { name: 'C' }]
const sortedData = _.orderBy(data, ['name'], ['asc'])
console.log(sortedData)
</script>
```